# Why does var bug = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10 equal 15

Tags: javascript, reactjs, flowtype

```
var bug = 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10
```

I am encountering this type of pattern in React and was confused by what it does. When I tried with numbers I get 15. How does that expressions sum to 15?

I realize now this is a Facebook Flow thing. I don't believe is Bitwise OR as marked.

Comment: Do you know what the `|` operator does?

Comment: Why do you think that expression is a sum?

Comment: Oh I was confusing it with the `||` operator, sorry

Comment: It's definitely a weird pattern though, given that it could have been replaced by a constant. Where exactly did you find this?

Comment: A lot of places, here: `export type TypeOfWork = 0 | 1 | 2 | 3 | 4 | 5 | 6 | 7 | 8 | 9 | 10;` in ReactTypeofWork.js and some other places.

Comment: I think I actually understood what `|` did but I just didn't believe that type of operator was being used in things like the above.

Comment: @chackerian Well that is whole different thing. It's a `type`, not a `var` as in your question, which means that it's TypeScript code where the operator means a completely different thing than bitwise OR. (While I don't know TypeScript, it sure looks like a separator between enum values).